# How to migrate WIndows Server 2008 firewall exceptions to a new environment?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, migration, windows-firewall

How to migrate Windows Server 2008 (and Windows 7) firewall exceptions to a new environment?

Specifically:

- SQL Server
- Subversion
- remote access?

Is if possible to use scripts like powershell?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wf.msc allows remote management of Windows Firewall running on other computers. You could connect and then use copy/paste to paste rules to the remote machine.

The easier alternative though is to use Windows Firewall's import/export feature (either via wf.msc or through netsh: "netsh advfirewall export c:\somedir\rules.wfw").

Comment: Which of the alternatives did the trick? Didn't understand how to connect remotely using wf.msc...?

Answer (score 1):

I did an export and import by selecting the rule and clicking copy. I then  RDP'd into the other servers, opened Firewall rules and clicked paste. It copied the rule. I also did this with four other servers.

Comment: This is, at most, a partial answer to the question. The question is how to migrate the entire exception set or chunks of it relating to a piece of software.

Comment: +1 - This was all I needed.